# .htaccess doesn't see the paramteres in an url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new to .htaccess and I am trying to 301 redirect an url with parameters to one without parameters but htaccess doesn't seem to get the parameters it just doesn't react to it.

```
RewriteRule index.php?pageid=8#menukarte http://test.myweb.nl/menukarte-restaurant-cuba-libre/ [NC,R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, you have to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageid=8$
RewriteRule index\.php$ http://test.myweb.nl/menukarte-restaurant-cuba-libre/ [NC,R=301,L,NE]
```

I'm assuming that the `#menukarte` is a URI fragment. When you see the `#` (and some text) at the end of a URL in the browser's location bar, that's purely a client side fragment and it never gets sent to the server. So there's no way you can match against that on the server.

Seeing that it may actually be what you're trying to do, htaccess isn't going to work for you and you're going to need to change the page's content (probably the scripts) such that the fragment causes the 301 redirect.

Comment: I just read that google doesn't index those pages anyway so I guess they arn't as important. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can't match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`. You must use `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageid=8$
RewriteRule index\.php$ http://test.myweb.nl/menukarte-restaurant-cuba-libre/ [NC,R=301,L,NE]
```

Also remember that part after `#` does not reach to web server.